# Providing only certain javascript parameters in method with default parameters

Tags: javascript

If I have a method like this 
`function something(a,b,c=5,d=10,e=false)`
and I want to provide only arguments a,b, and e and let the remainder be set to their defaults.

In python I would issue a call to this function like:

`k = something(a,b,e=True)`

but is there an equivalent way to specify only one default parameter in Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to fill in the missing ones with `undefined`:

```
k = something(a, b, undefined, undefined, true)
```

---

Although, the better would be to rewrite your function to receive an options parameter as argument instead:

```
function something(a, b, options) {
    if (options.c === undefined) options.c = 5;
    if (options.d === undefined) options.d = 10;
    if (options.e === undefined) options.e = false;
    // use options.c, options.d and options.e here
    // (give better names to them of course)
}

k = something(a, b, { e: true })
```

Or with ES6 destructuring assignment syntax:

```
function something(a, b, { c=5, d=10, e=false }) {
    // use c, d and e directly here
    // (again, you should give better names to them of course)
}

k = something(a, b, { e: true })
```

This is the usual way to approach "named parameters" from Python in javascript. Since there is no way to refer to the named parameters directly (as you do in python), in JavaScript we often use an `options` parameter (which is a plain object than can be easily created inline). When you get used to this syntax, you'll see it is almost the same thing as in python.